# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier crash in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

i'm doing a project in iOS, The main project is a tab bar app, and two of the tabs have a Navigation controller, a UItableview and a detail view. The problem occurs when a click in the cell to go to the detail view. My application Crash. This is what i did:

1. I put the UITableView
2. I Embed the table into a Navigation controller
3. I create the detail view
4. I create the segues manually
5. I name the segues
6. I add the Storyboard ID to each viewcontroller.

Then in my UItableViewController I add the code to load the data from a sqlite database.
And i put the next code to go to the detail view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailView * newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DetailView animated:YES];

}
```

This it the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "tzk-6A-7EG-view-Jev-6n-BAZ" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Which more should I do? perhaps i'm missing some code, i'm very new to iOS, this is my first project.

Comment: Do you have a VC with an id "DetailView" in your Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to put that... i have a Storyboard ID "DetailView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the name is correct you entered .
Steps i will follow

1. Add a UIViewController/UITableviewcontroller
2. Embed it with navigation controller
3. Add a tableview(connect datasource and delegate and outlet it exist)
4. add a storyboardId
5. Copy-Paste that name and add it to the code where push is
   implemented

Delete the app from simulator build and run again.

Comment: are you subclassing a UITableviewController?

Comment: Yes, i'm subclassing a UITableviewController! that's the mistake, it should be a UIViewController! THANK YOU!